# "Improved" MZT/IIM type One pole LPF

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, approximation

Some time ago, while playing with all kind of approximation of common math functions, I came up to this idea to calculate *a1* coefficient for a one pole low pass filter:

\begin{array}{l}a1=-(1+x+\frac12x^2),\;where\;\\x\;=\frac1{fT},\;\\f=sampling\;frequecy\;(Hz),\;\\T=time\;constant\;(\mu s)\end{array}

so the final filter would be (Octave code):

```
% --------------------
% OCTAVE PACKAGES 
% --------------------
pkg load signal
% --------------------

clf

fs=44100;
fc=10000;
fct=1/(2*pi*fc);
fs2 = fs/2;
N=1; % order

% --------------------
% MZT approximated
% --------------------
x = 1.0/(fs*fct); 
MZTa0 = 1.0;
MZTa1 = -(1 + x + 0.5 * x^2); 
MZTb0 = MZTa0 + MZTa1; 
MZTb1 = 0.0; 

MZTa = [MZTa0 MZTa1];
MZTb = [MZTb0 MZTb1];

MZT2=tf(MZTb, MZTa, 1/fs);

% --------------------
% Analog model
% --------------------
w0 = 2*pi*fc;
Analogb = 1;
Analoga = [1 w0];
Analog = tf(Analogb, Analoga);
Analog = Analog/dcgain(Analog);

% --------------------
% MZT
% --------------------
p1 = exp(-1.0/(fs*(1/(2 * pi * fc))))
z1 = 0.0;                            
MZTa0 = 1.0;
MZTa1 = -p1; 
MZTb0 = 1.0-p1;
MZTb1 = -z1; 

MZTa = [MZTa0 MZTa1];
MZTb = [MZTb0 MZTb1];

MZT=tf(MZTb, MZTa, 1/fs);

% --------------------
% IIM
% --------------------
[IIMb,IIMa]=impinvar(Analogb,Analoga,fs); 
IIM=tf(IIMb, IIMa, 1/fs);
IIM=IIM/dcgain(IIM);
  
% --------------------
% BLT 
% --------------------
w0 = 2*pi*(fc/fs);
BLTb0 =   sin(w0);
BLTb1 =   sin(w0);
BLTa0 =   cos(w0) + sin(w0) + 1.0;
BLTa1 =   sin(w0) - cos(w0) - 1.0;

BLTa = [BLTa0 BLTa1];
BLTb = [BLTb0 BLTb1];

BLT=tf(BLTb, BLTa, 1/fs);
BLT=BLT/dcgain(BLT);

BLT = c2d(Analog, 1/fs, 'prewarp', w0);

% --------------------
% Plot
% --------------------

nf = logspace(0, 5, fs2);

figure(1);
% analog model
[mag, pha] = bode(Analog,2*pi*nf);
semilogx(nf, 20*log10(abs(mag)), 'color', 'g', 'linewidth', 2);
axis([10 fs2 -30 1]);
hold on;
%semilogx(nf, pha, 'color', 'g', 'linewidth', 2, 'linestyle', '--'); %hold on;

% BLT
[mag, pha] = bode(BLT,2*pi*nf);
semilogx(nf, 20*log10(abs(mag)), 'color', 'm', 'linewidth', 1.0, 'linestyle', '-'); hold on;
%semilogx(nf, pha, 'color', 'm'); %hold on;

% MZT
[mag, pha] = bode(MZT,2*pi*nf);
semilogx(nf, 20*log10(abs(mag)), 'color', 'k', 'linewidth', 1.0, 'linestyle', '-'); hold on;
%semilogx(nf, pha, 'color', 'k', 'linewidth', 1.0, 'linestyle', '--'); %hold on;

% IIM
[mag, pha] = bode(IIM,2*pi*nf);
semilogx(nf, 20*log10(abs(mag)), 'color', 'c', 'linewidth', 1.0, 'linestyle', '--'); hold on;
%semilogx(nf, pha, 'color', 'c', 'linewidth', 1.0, 'linestyle', '--'); %hold on;

% MZT approximated
[mag, pha] = bode(MZT2,2*pi*nf);
semilogx(nf, 20*log10(abs(mag)), 'color', 'r', 'linewidth', 2.0, 'linestyle', '--'); hold on;
%semilogx(nf, -pha, 'color', 'r', 'linewidth', 2.0, 'linestyle', '--'); %hold on;

grid on;

str=num2str(fs);
str2=num2str(fc);
str3=num2str(N);

str = sprintf("LPF (various TF), order:%s, fs=%s, fc=%s, ",str3, str, str2); 
title(str);
legend('Analog', 'BLT', 'MZT', 'IIM', 'MZTapprox', 'location', 'southwest');
xlabel('Hz');ylabel('dB');
```

By octave plots, frequency response improves a bit when cut-off frequency is closing fs/2:

[image]

and by phase plot:

[image]

response differs a lot from the original MZT.

Idea here is to use the approximation error of low degree [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) $e^x$ approximation to cancel the error found in standard [MZT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_Z-transform_method) (/[IIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_invariance)) transform method. When higher degree polynomial is used the error decreases and the resulting filter closes the original MZT/IIM responses. See the values for *s*, *c* and *v*, *v2*: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s5wftcupmr

Questions:

1. Any thoughts on possible drawbacks in calculating one pole LP filter this way?
2. Is the phase response an issue (it is -180° at Nyquist frequency when std MZT goes to 0° ?

Comment: I get that IIM means Impulse Invariance Method.

What does MZT mean?

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: it's the [Matched Z-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_Z-transform_method), @Ben .  the most simple.  just map the analog poles and zeros to the digital poles and zeros using $z=e^{sT}$.

Comment: You should add this info in your question.